# about strengthening wood plank end grain from splitting

Tags: woodworking

I am thinking about strengthening wood plank end grain by gluing another piece of same type of wood, with perpendicular grain directions. See the picture below:
[image]

The longer plank will be about 1 inch thick. Naively thinking, the smaller piece should be of comparable thickness. I am wondering if this sort of structure is stable in long run. Will it split? If not, what is the best thickness?

Comment: Wood changes dimension across the grain in response to changes in humidity. So, in general, any two pieces glued with perpendicular grain will cause one to split. Without knowing the specific sizes involved or the exact construction problem you're trying to solve it will be difficult to suggest the correct solution.

Comment: Have you encountered a problem with planks splitting at the ends?  Are there environmental factors that make this a problem?  What kind of planks?  What kind of application?

Comment: @fixer1234 I haven't encountered splitting. I just want to know if this idea will work or not. I want to do this kind of cross joint (link: https://homemade-furniture.com/woodworking-joints/halved-joint/), but between two ends of two 1 inch thick white oak planks. Cross joint at plank end will obviously create a weak point.